# how to get form field's field type

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to get field's model type or form type in Django's ModelForm.

models.py

```
class Offer(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    start_date = models.DateField()
```

forms.py

```
class OfferForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Offer
```

add_offer.html

```
{% for form in offer_form %}
    {% if form.field_type??? = 'DateField' %}
        {# add some class or something ??? #}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

In python console everything is pretty good. I mean

```
print field.__class__.__name__
>>> 'DateField'
```

but i want to create template tag and results are here:

```
print field.__class__.__name__
>>> 'BoundField'
```

what can i do about that ?

Comment: i solve the problem with form widgets and adding some class to desired field but its hardcoded. I want to use more generic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django wraps form fields in templates with the `BoundField` class. To access proper field class use BoundField's `field` attribute. Example:

```
{{ login_form.username.field }}
```

To access widget:

```
{{ login_form.username.field.widget }}
```

Note that you wont be able to access field's class in template. All identifiers starting with an underscore are not accessible in templates.

If you want to customize form rendering, then you have at least these options:

1. Assign chosen [widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/widgets/) to form fields. If any of Django widgets doesn't provide functionality you want, then you need to create an own widget (usually subclassing builtin widget).
2. Use different HTML templates to render particular form fields. This is rather a lot of work to write all those templates, but usually pays up, because gives a lot of flexibility.
3. Find a library, that allows to use HTML templates from #2 (on [djangopackages.com](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/forms/) maybe).

Comment: thanks for your response, but every solution except #1, needs a lot of work. i stay with the hardcoded widgets just for now.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> f.formfield().widget
<django.forms.widgets.TextInput object at 0x1125fc690>
>>> f.formfield().widget
<django.forms.widgets.TextInput object at 0x1125fc710>
>>> dir(f.formfield().widget)
['__class__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_format_value', 'attrs', 'build_attrs', 'id_for_label', 'input_type', 'is_hidden', 'is_localized', 'is_required', 'media', 'needs_multipart_form', 'render', 'subwidgets', 'value_from_datadict']
>>> f.formfield().widget.attrs
{u'maxlength': '10'}
>>> f.formfield().widget.input_type
u'text'
>>>
```

so i think you can use `{{ login_form.username.field.widget.input_type }}`

Answer (score 0):

```
 {% if 'date' in field|field_type %}
       {% render_field field class="form-control is-valid" type="date" %}
 {% else %}
       {% render_field field class="form-control is-valid" %}
 {% endif %}
```

¡Hope this helps!